# confused with partition inked lists

Tags: linked-list

Given a linked list and a target value T, partition it such that all nodes less than T are listed before the nodes larger than or equal to target value T.

I found it is a little confused to me to understand codes.

```
while(head!=null){
  if(head.value<target){
    curSmall.next=head;
    curSmall=curSmall.next;
  } else{
    curLarge.next=head;
    curLarge=curLarge.next;
  }
  head=head.next;
}
curSmall.next=large.next;
curLarge.next=null;
return small.next;
```

I just don't understand these two parts `large.next` and `return small.next`? 
In other word, when we connect the small and large linked list, the `curSmall.next` --> `large.next`, why we put large.next here, I am quite confused. And why we need to return `small.next`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, after while loop of that code, two linked list are like below.

> dummy_head(small)->a->c->d
>
> dummy_head(large)->f->h

And curSmall and curLarge points the node 'd' and 'h' respectively.
Therefore you can get a desired linked list in the following steps.

1. The small linked list append the large linked list
   => curSmall.next = large.next;
2. The tail node 'h' of large linked list points to null => curLarge.next = null;
3. Return the head node 'a' of entire linked list => return small.next;